# Can't create a collection on mongo database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

I am trying to create a collection in a mongo database through mongoDB compass. However, I get an error that says it is not authorized on the database to execute the command.

As well as this, when i do `show dbs` in the mongo shell I can only see one of the databases I have created (I can't even see admin, config or local), whereas I can see all of them in mongoDB compass. If I then try to create the data base in the mongo shell, i.e

```
use [database name]

db.createUser({...})
```

I get an error like this `uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: not authorized on [database name] to execute command`

but if I use admin first then I get this error `uncaught exception: Error: couldn't add user: logical sessions can't have multiple authenticated users`

Using `db.auth` first works and returns, 1. But then the rest of the errors just appear when I try everything else.

Does anyone know what is going on here? My databases have nothing in them and I don't know how to fix this

Comment: try https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.auth/

Comment: Use the [connectionStatus](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/connectionStatus/) command to see the current authenticated user and granted roles

Comment: Hey @dododo, I have tried use admin then db.auth which works and returns a 1 but then the other errors still happen afterwards